# VBA code - find and replace format of a single value

Tags: excel, vba, replace, format, find

Could someone please help with the find and replacing the format of a single digit, i.e. cell has a value "1,10,11,5", and am I looking to color and change the format of value 11, and want to keep other values intact. Find and replace does work but changes font and size of complete cell instead of just "11".

```
Range("I2:M14").Select
Selection.Replace What:="11,", Replacement:="11,", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=True
```

Comment: You need to use Instr() to locate the "11", then use the `Characters` collection to format the relevant charaters in the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Replacing in Excel with the format doesn not produce the desired results.
- You need to find the keyword for each cell and change its format.
- Locating the number `11` within a cell containing `11,` is not reliable. For example, if the cell value is `2,111,33,11`, it accidentally matches part of `111` and misses the last `11`. Changing the keyword to `,11,` would be more reliable.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim c As Range, sTxt As String, iLoc As Long
    Const KEYWORD = ",11,"
    For Each c In Range("I2:M14")
        sTxt = c.Value
        If Len(sTxt) > 0 Then
            sTxt = "," & sTxt & ","
            iLoc = InStr(sTxt, KEYWORD)
            If iLoc > 0 Then
                c.Characters(iLoc, Len(KEYWORD) - 2).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```